# Closed form of $\int_{B_r(x_0)} |x|^\alpha \,dx$?

Tags: asymptotics, closed-form

Is there a closed form for the integral $$\int_{B_r(x_0)} |x|^\alpha \,dx$$ where $B_r(x_0)$ denotes the a ball of radius $r$ and centre $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\alpha > -n$ and $x_0 \neq 0$?

After rescaling and orthogonal change of coordinates it reduces to $\displaystyle r^{n + \alpha}\int_{B_1(0)} |x + (\lambda,0')|^\alpha\,dx$ where, $\lambda = r^{-1}|x_0|$ and $0' \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. Is there a way of evaluating this integral or perhaps finding the asymptotic behavior in terms of $\lambda$?

Comment: I think you can take away the $r$.  We know to multiply the result for a unit sphere by $r^n$ well.